# Get specific xml node with xml:id attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xml-parsing

I am using jquery to get node's values and texts.

This is my .xml:

```
<div xml:id = "pe007">
<persName>
<surname>Smith</surname
</persName>
</div>
```

This is my js code:

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "myfile.xml",
dataType: "xml",
success: function (xml) {

var surname = $(xml).find('div[xml:id="pe007"] > surname').text();

}});
```

I already know how to get text and value of nodes. I just want to select a specific node. When the attribute is something like 'ref', I have no issues of getting what I want (with `.attr("ref")`). But jquery seems not to like this expression:

```
'div[xml:id="pe007"]'
```

In fact I get

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: div[xml:id="pe007"] > surname
```

Why is div[ref="pe007"] OK and not xml:id? Is it something to do with the colon? I really need to access the children of a div with a specific xml:id attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was relatively simple: I had to escape the colon with `\\`, so:

```
var surname = $(xml).find('div[xml\\:id="pe007"] > surname').text();
```

works.